# Ubuntu 12.04: Errors in sudo apt-get update

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I've been getting this reoccurring error whenever I "sudo apt-get update" on Ubuntu 12.04

```
W: GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following signatures 
couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 082CCEDF94558F59
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbzr-
dev/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbzr-dev/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-
i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

I'm a bit new to ubuntu, but I wanted to figure out how I can go about fixing this issue.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have the spotify signing key. Try;

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 082CCEDF94558F59
```

and update again. Spotify also has another key (for newer versions?)

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59
```

but that doesn't seem to be what your apt is complaining about.

Comment: Thank Joachim. That was able to clear up the Spotify error. 

Do you have any idea why my Bazaar Explorer is throwing errors?

Comment: It's okay. I was able to figure it out. There were a few add-ons available on the Ubuntu Software Center for the Explorer that were necessary.